# javascript turn off code formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code, autoformatting

vscode is great, but it oversteps boundaries. I'd like to maintain my coding style but seem to be constantly forced into some invisible 'standard', defined by MSoft, I suppose.  At any rate, I have `"javascript.format.enable": false` set and yet it still insists on changing my code.

Take something simple, like dothis(y+2), gets converted to dothis(y + 2) on Save (Ctrl-S). There are many times when I just want what I typed in. How can I get vscode to help me out instead of imposing its own 'standard'?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have `"editor.formatOnSave": true` in user settings or folder settings? Or, an extension installed that may be doing this?